# I can't fullscreen certain games, native or otherwise: Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wine, games, steam, 20.10, fullscreen

Certain games when launched from Steam are unable to be fullscreened. It doesn't happen with every game but it doesn't seem to matter if it is Linux native or not. The in game options do not allow me to fullscreen the game. Alt+Enter also does nothing. Some notable examples are:

Half-Life 2: The game is stuck at 800x640. No amount of launch options changes this.
Black Mesa: See above.
Kerbal Space Program: Stuck in windowed mode.
Left 4 Dead 2: Stuck in a pseudo windowed mode where it is the full resolution of my monitor but is offset by the Activities bar and Taskbar. Most other games that are affected by this problem have this effect.
Tabletop Simulator: See above.
Max Payne: See above.
BeamNG.drive: See above.

As you can probably tell, this is really annoying and I don't know why it started. A few months ago it was fine. I have looked as best I could on the internet to find people with similar problems but I can't find anyone.

Below you will find my PC details from the Steam System Information:

Computer Information:
Manufacturer:  Unknown
Model:  Unknown
Form Factor: Desktop
No Touch Input Detected

Processor Information:
CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
CPU Brand:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
CPU Family:  0x6
CPU Model:  0x9e
CPU Stepping:  0xa
CPU Type:  0x0
Speed:  4700 Mhz
12 logical processors
6 physical processors
HyperThreading:  Supported
FCMOV:  Supported
SSE2:  Supported
SSE3:  Supported
SSSE3:  Supported
SSE4a:  Unsupported
SSE41:  Supported
SSE42:  Supported
AES:  Supported
AVX:  Supported
AVX2:  Unsupported
AVX512F:  Unsupported
AVX512PF:  Unsupported
AVX512ER:  Unsupported
AVX512CD:  Unsupported
AVX512VNNI:  Unsupported
SHA:  Unsupported
CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
Ubuntu 20.10 (64 bit)
Kernel Name:  Linux
Kernel Version:  5.8.0-38-generic
X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
X Server Release:  12009000
X Window Manager:  GNOME Shell
Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime_0.20201203.1

Video Card:
Driver:  NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2
Driver Version:  4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.32.03
OpenGL Version: 4.6
Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
Monitor Refresh Rate: 59 Hz
VendorID:  0x10de
DeviceID:  0x1b81
Revision Not Detected
Number of Monitors:  3
Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
Primary Display Resolution:  3840 x 2160
Desktop Resolution: 6784 x 2160
Primary Display Size: 23.62" x 13.39" (27.13" diag)
60.0cm x 34.0cm (68.9cm diag)
Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
Primary VRAM: 8192 MB
Supported MSAA Modes:  2x 4x 8x 16x

Sound card:
Audio device: Realtek ALC892

Memory:
RAM:  48122 Mb

VR Hardware:
Headset: HTC Vive. MV (lighthouse)

Miscellaneous:
UI Language:  English
LANG:  en_US.UTF-8
Total Hard Disk Space Available:  2815643 Mb
Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  1091725 Mb

Comment: Same problem here too, also been looking for a solution. NVidia 2080 Super here and the 460.32.03 drivers, but had it before that too. KSP, Wasteland 2, and others. Starting from cli outside of Steam is windowed as well

Comment: After doing some searches, I found this, going to try it out; https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1534

Comment: Confirmed, KSP and other games now work correctly with that patch installed in the list. Now just need for it to be rolled out officially

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I guess I'll call that the answer? IDK how stack exchange works lol.